# How to integrate twitter with custom login like opinion lab in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, twitter, twitter-oauth, sharekit

Hi i want to integrate twitter application with custom login and custom window i have already used twitter+oath kinda Api i want to implement like [opinionlab](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opinionlab-feedback/id341889514?mt=8) and [push a deal](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/push-a-deal/id418897508?mt=8) here in both application you can see custom twitter integration (respect GUI) how can i integrate like this [please refer my already asked question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947723/how-to-tweet-with-some-prepopulated-text-in-twitter-in-iphone-sdk) [image: i have add some images from opinion lab and push a deal application.] this is sample image can anybody guide me how to integrate like this i have already seen many examples. but i can't get it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the one who actually wrote the the OpinionLab App. It's just a web view. Send it the url like https://twitter.com/share?text=(Fill in your text here)